# How to change images base on data(json file) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fiddling with jquery and json, basically trying to make a weather website that shows weather of 4 cities. I want to display images according to the data, but my javascript seems to have some problem...

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weather-graphic</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="HK tooltip">Hong Kong
        <span class="p1 tooltiptext"></span>
</div>

<div class="NY tooltip">New York
        <span class="p2 tooltiptext"></span>
</div>

<div class="A tooltip">Auckland
        <span class="p3 tooltiptext"></span>
</div>

<div class="R tooltip">Wādī Ḩalfā
        <span class="p4 tooltiptext"></span>
</div>
<div id="img" class="h"></div>
<div id="img" class="n"></div>
<div id="img" class="al"></div>
<div id="img" class="w"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
.HK{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left:180px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.p1{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
 text-align: left;
 display:block;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 40px;
 /*margin: 0 auto;
 width: 450px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-left: 200px;*/
}
.NY{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:190px;
    padding-top: 170px;
}
.p2{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
 text-align: left;
 display:block;
 font-size: 25px;
 line-height: 40px;
 /*margin: 0 auto;
 width: 320px;
 margin-top: 280px;
 margin-left:200px;
 line-height: 25px;*/

}
.A{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:absolute;
    left:-570px;
    top:370px;
}
.p3{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 40px;
    /*position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    top: 230px;
    line-height: 25px;
    left: 800px;*/
}
.R{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:absolute;
    left:580px;
    top:320px;
}
.p4{
    font-family:futura-pt, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 40px;
    /*position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    top: 630px;
    line-height: 25px;
    left: 800px;*/
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity:40%;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
.h{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:100vh auto;
    height: 100vh auto;
    z-index:-2;
}
.n{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:300vh auto;
    height: 100vh auto;
    z-index:-2;
}
.al{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:100vh auto;
    height: 300vh auto;
    z-index:-2;
}
.w{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    width:300vh auto;
    height: 300vh auto;
    z-index:-2;
}
```

*BELOW ARE JAVASCRIPT FILE*

This is an example of one of the API Weather data that I get from the website, and this part works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?balabalabalabala....', //random url
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(results){
            temp = results.main.temp;
            humidity = results.main.humidity;
            visibility = results.visibility;

            myWeatherInterpretation();
        }
    });
    function myWeatherInterpretation(){

        //JUST SEEING IF THE VALUES COME THROUGH
        $('.p1').append('Temperature: ' + temp + " " + '°C' + '</br>');
        $('.p1').append('Humidity: ' + humidity + " " + '%' + '</br>');
        $('.p1').append('Visibility: ' + visibility + " " + 'm' + '</br>');
    } 
});
```

Problem starts from here:

```
function changeImage (){
        var img = document.getElementById("img");
        var t = data.main.temp;
        var h = data.main.humidity;
        var v = data.main.visibility;
        img.src = images[x];
        x++;

        if(v>10000 && 0=<h<30 && t=<0){
            x=0;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 0=<h<30 && 0<t<10){
            x=1;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 0=<h<30 && 10=<t<20){
            x=2;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 0=<h<30 && 20=<t<30){
            x=3;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 0=<h<30 && t>=30){
            x=4;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 30=<h<60 && t=<0){
            x=5;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 30=<h<60 && 0<t<10){
            x=6;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 30=<h<60 && 10=<t<20){
            x=7;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 30=<h<60 && 20=<t<30){
            x=8;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 30=<h<60 && t>=30){
            x=9;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 60=<h<85 &&  t=<0){
            x=10;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 60=<h<85 &&  0<t<10){
            x=11;

        if(v>10000 && 60=<h<85 &&  10=<t<20){
            x=12;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 60=<h<85 &&  20=<t<30){
            x=13;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 60=<h<85 &&  t>=30){
            x=14;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 85=<h=<100 &&  t=<0){
            x=15;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 85=<h=<100 && 0<t<10){
            x=16;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 85=<h=<100 && 10=<t<20){
            x=17;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 85=<h=<100 && 20=<t<30){
            x=18;
        }
        if(v>10000 && 85=<h=<100 && t>=30){
            x=19;
        }
        if(v=<10000 && 0=<h<30 && t=<0){
            x=20;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 0=<h<30 && 0<t<10){
            x=21;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 0=<h<30 && 10=<t<20){
            x=22;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 0=<h<30 && 20=<t<30){
            x=23;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 0=<h<30 && t>=30){
            x=24;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 30=<h<60 && t=<0){
            x=25;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 30=<h<60 && 0<t<10){
            x=26;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 30=<h<60 && 10=<t<20){
            x=27;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 30=<h<60 && 20=<t<30{
            x=28;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 30=<h<60 && t>=30){
            x=29;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 60=<h<85 && t=<0){
            x=30;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 60=<h<85 && 0<t<10){
            x=31;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 60=<h<85 && 10=<t<20){
            x=32;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 60=<h<85 && 20=<t<30){
            x=33;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 60=<h<85 && t>=30){
            x=34;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 85=<h=<100 && t=<0){
            x=35;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 85=<h=<100 && 0<t<10){
            x=36;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 85=<h=<100 && 10=<t<20){
            x=37;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 85=<h=<100 && 20=<t<30){
            x=38;
        }
        if( v=<10000 && 85=<h=<100 && t>=30){
            x=39
        }

        //explanation of the name of the images:
        //v>10000-c v=<10000-m 
        //0=<h<30-1 30=<h<60-2 60=<h<85-3 85=<h=<100-4
        //t=<0-b 0<t<10-t 10=<t<20-y 20=<t<30-o t>=30-r

        var images = [], x =0;
        images[3] = 'image/1oc.png';
        images[23] = 'image/1om.png';
        images[4] = 'image/1rc.png';
        images[24] = 'image/1rm.png';
        images[2] = 'image/1yc.png';
        images[22] = 'image/1ym.png';
        images[1] = 'image/1tc.png';
        images[21] = 'image/1tm.png';
        images[0] = 'image/1bc.png';
        images[20] = 'image/1bm.png';
        images[8] = 'image/2oc.png';
        images[28] = 'image/2om.png';
        images[9] = 'image/2rc.png';
        images[29] = 'image/2rm.png';
        images[7] = 'image/2yc.png';
        images[27] = 'image/2ym.png';
        images[6] = 'image/2tc.png';
        images[26] = 'image/2tm.png';
        images[5] = 'image/2bc.png';
        images[25] = 'image/2bm.png';
        images[13] = 'image/3oc.png';
        images[33] = 'image/3om.png';
        images[14] = 'image/3rc.png';
        images[34] = 'image/3rm.png';
        images[12] = 'image/3yc.png';
        images[32] = 'image/3ym.png';
        images[11] = 'image/3tc.png';
        images[31] = 'image/3tm.png';
        images[10] = 'image/3bc.png';
        images[30] = 'image/3bm.png';
        images[18] = 'image/4oc.png';
        images[38] = 'image/4om.png';
        images[19] = 'image/4rc.png';
        images[39] = 'image/4rm.png';
        images[17] = 'image/4yc.png';
        images[37] = 'image/4ym.png';
        images[16] = 'image/4tc.png';
        images[36] = 'image/4tm.png';
        images[14] = 'image/4bc.png';
        images[34] = 'image/4bm.png';

        }
    }
```

I expected it to have one image behind the city name to show the weather and the image changes as the weather data changes all the time. When mouse on the name of the city, the data will show below the name(and I've done it). However, no image shows in my code, even the mouse-on thing disappeared when I added image-changing javascript. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your JavaScript code has some syntax errors. Expressions like `0=<h<30` are not valid. It should be written as `0 <= h && h < 30` You should also consider refactoring that large list of `if` statements

Comment: You need to debug this in the browser console (press F12) or whatever IDE you are using (even jsfiddle.net has basic syntax checks) - these will show you where your code has obvious errors such as those highlighted above.

Comment: where were you calling this method changeImage () in your code??